# storing huge amount of json data into a database

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb

I am new to programming in HTML, Javascript and PHP. I have huge amount of JSON data which I need to store somewhere secure. I was hoping to store it in a MYSQL database.

Options I have considered till now :

1. json.stringify and then store it in a mysql table
2. Use a database which supports JSON format like postgres, mongoDB

I want to know which option will be more efficient and simple since I am new to this.

If possible, please provide code snippets or links to tutorials.

Any help would be great! Thanks so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Coming from PHP, use `$str = json_encode($json);`, then store the result in a `TEXT` column in your table.  If TEXT is not big enough (limit 64K), use MEDIUMINT (limit 16MB).

For retrieving, use `$json = json_decode($txt, true)`.

Note that this assumes you do not need to look at the fields in the JSON, but are simply storing and retrieving an 'opaque' object.